# Manga where the main character is living their fourth life

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I've been searching for this manga for a while, but can't remember the name. All I remember is that in the first chapter, the main character dies and is reincarnated as a warrior, then works his way up to being called a blade master or sword saint. When he dies, he's again reincarnated and this time tries his hand at magic, being later called a sage or whatever. In his fourth life, he wants to do something different, but I can't remember what.

Any help with locating this manga, or someone confirming I was tripping balls on LSD when thinking of a story like this is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, do you remember any other characters in the story?

Comment: I can't remember any characters since I only read the first chapter. From what I can recall, the first chapter didn't even provide the mc's name since he lived many lives. Also it was definitely black and white

Answer (score 3):

This may be *[Shijou Saikyou no Mahou Kenshi, F-Rank Boukensha ni Tensei suru: Kensei to Matei, 2-tsu no Zense wo motta Otoko no Eiyuutan](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shijou-saikyou-no-mahou-kenshi-f-rank-boukensha-ni-tensei-suru-kensei-to-matei-2-tsu-no-zense-wo-motta-otoko-no-eiyuutan)*.

> Aizawa Yuri has reincarnated 2 times now and is dead tired of being the emperor of this and that. Using his skills, he aquired a reincarnation artifact, and starts his life in a brand new world!

Some details don't match, but the general idea of the story does. Aizawa Yuri is a Japanese man in his thirties who is taken to another world; there he learns magic and becomes a master of magic. He reincarnates and learns the sword instead, and becomes a master of the sword (this is the "this and that" in the synopsis)

[image: Main character becomes magic emperor] [image: Main character becomes god of swords]

The order doesn't match, and he transmigrates rather than dying, but he basically lives 3 different lives there.

The very start of the story is him fighting against a giant monster to obtain a resurrection crystal, which he uses to reincarnate and live a fourth life, where he more or less tries to be unremarkable.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm checking it out now!

Comment: @Myst_Assist You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).